# Impala: all DISTINCT aggregate functions need to have the same set of parameters

Tags: sql, hdfs, impala

I got the following error in my Impala query:

```
select 
   upload_key, 
   max(my_timestamp) as upload_time, 
   max(color_key) as max_color_fk, 
   count(distinct color_key) as color_count, 
   count(distinct id) as toy_count 
from upload_table 
group by upload_key
```

---

and got the error:

> AnalysisException: all DISTINCT aggregate functions need to have the
>   same set of parameters as count(DISTINCT color_key); deviating
>   function: count(DISTINCT id)

I am not sure why I got this error. What I did was for each group (grouped by `upload_key`), I tried to compute how many `distinct id` as well as how many `distinct color_key`. 
Does any one have any idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message indicates that `DISTINCT` is only allowed on one *column [combination]*, but you try two, `color_key`& `id`. A workaround would be two Selects and then a join:

```
select
   t1.upload_key,
   t1.upload_time,
   t1.max_color_fk,
   t1.color_count,
   t2.toy_count
from
 (
   select 
      upload_key, 
      max(my_timestamp) as upload_time, 
      max(color_key) as max_color_fk, 
      count(distinct color_key) as color_count
   from upload_table 
   group by upload_key
 ) as t1
join
 (
   select 
      upload_key
      count(distinct id) as toy_count 
   from upload_table 
   group by upload_key
 ) as t2
on t1. upload_key = t2.upload_key
```